# HTML Anchor to calendar?

Tags: html, uri, anchor

Is there a way to make a generic link to create a calendar event as an HTML anchor's URI? For instance, you can make a link that creates an email with `<a href="mailto:address@example.com?Subject=Subject%20line&body=Body%20content.">Link text</a>`, and you can make a link that initiates a phone call with `<a href="callto:5551234567">Link text</a>`. **Is there such a syntax for calendars that is NOT program specific?** (I know there are things like `outlook://` and iCal can use `.ics` files, but I want a program-agnostic one)

I'm looking for something like `<a href="cal:Event%20title?start=timestamp&end=timestamp&description=Arbitrary%20description%20text>Link text</a>`

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to use a combination of the [`webcal`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webcal) link as well as a dynamically created ics file.  Usage of `webcal` would be as follows:

```
<a href="webcal://createCal.php?title=Title&amp;start=timestamp&amp;end=timestamp&amp;description=Arbitrary%20description%20text">Link</a>
```

However, for best compatibility, I think your best bet would be to just link directly to the `ics` file:

```
<a href="createCal.php?title=Title&amp;start=timestamp&amp;end=timestamp&amp;description=Arbitrary%20description%20text">Link</a>
```

Then, in the `createCal.php` file (or whichever your programming language of choice is) you could do something similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5750249/create-ics-file-dynamically) article to create an `ics` file on the fly that the user could import into their calendar program of choice.

Here's another sample I found for the contents of the PHP file (note that this isn't tested, but more so a starting point):

```
<?php
//Set the content-type of the file
header("Content-Type: text/Calendar");
header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=Calendar.ics");
echo "BEGIN:VCALENDAR\n";
echo "PRODID:-//Microsoft Corporation//Outlook 12.0 MIMEDIR//EN\n";
echo "VERSION:2.0\n";
echo "METHOD:PUBLISH\n";
echo "X-MS-OLK-FORCEINSPECTOROPEN:TRUE\n";
echo "BEGIN:VEVENT\n";
echo "CLASS:PUBLIC\n";
echo "CREATED:".date('Ymd\THis', time())."\n";
echo "DESCRIPTION:".$_GET['description'];
echo "DTEND:".date('Ymd\THis', $_GET['end'])."\n";
echo "DTSTAMP:".date('Ymd\THis', time())."\n";
echo "DTSTART:".date('Ymd\THis', $_GET['start'])."\n";
echo "LAST-MODIFIED:".date('Ymd\THis', time())."\n";
echo "LOCATION:\n";
echo "PRIORITY:5\n";
echo "SEQUENCE:0\n";
echo "SUMMARY;LANGUAGE=en-us:".$_GET['title']."\n";
echo "TRANSP:OPAQUE\n";
echo "UID:040000008200E00074C5B7101A82E008000000008062306C6261CA01000000000000000\n";
echo "X-MICROSOFT-CDO-BUSYSTATUS:BUSY\n";
echo "X-MICROSOFT-CDO-IMPORTANCE:1\n";
echo "X-MICROSOFT-DISALLOW-COUNTER:FALSE\n";
echo "X-MS-OLK-ALLOWEXTERNCHECK:TRUE\n";
echo "X-MS-OLK-AUTOFILLLOCATION:FALSE\n";
echo "X-MS-OLK-CONFTYPE:0\n";
//Here is to set the reminder for the event.
echo "BEGIN:VALARM\n";
echo "TRIGGER:-PT1440M\n";
echo "ACTION:DISPLAY\n";
echo "DESCRIPTION:Reminder\n";
echo "END:VALARM\n";
echo "END:VEVENT\n";
echo "END:VCALENDAR\n";
?>
```

Comment: I was hoping for pure HTML, as the servers I'm using this on don't all necessarily have PHP installed.

Comment: I'm not sure you can accomplish this with pure html, unless you have a different `.ics` file for each calendar item that you want them to be able to download.

Comment: No, I don't want to use `.ics` files, as I said in my question

Comment: Unfortunately I think you're out of luck.  Sorry

Comment: Thanks, anyway. +1 for the effort and friendliness!