# Calendar on website - make it subscribable for .ics / ICAL

Tags: fullcalendar, icalendar

How do I make a ICal subscription link on website, so people can subscribe to my calendar?
Currently I'm thinking of using http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/, with all the events in a MySQL database.
Can I use this Calendar or shall I use another one?
I have searched for this subscribable feature here on Stack Overflow and on google without luck, so I hope any of you can help me?

Answer (score 1):

Since version [v5.5.0](https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/releases/tag/v5.5.0) FullCalendar can now also independently read in ics files and display them accordingly. A simple example can be found in the [documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v5/icalendar):

```
import dayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid'
import iCalendarPlugin from '@fullcalendar/icalendar'

var calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {
  plugins: [dayGridPlugin, iCalendarPlugin],
  events: {
    url: 'https://mywebsite/icalendar-feed.ics',
    format: 'ics'
  }
})

calendar.render()
```

Answer (score 0):

FullCalendar is great, but it doesn't offer an iCal or .ics feed itself. To use FullCalendar, you will need to provide it with the list of events you want it to display - the events in your database. Whatever code you use to generate that list, you can use as the base to create a feed of the events in an ics or iCal compatible format as a separate call (much like generating an RSS feed).

Not sure what language you are using but this PHP to .ics question may help point you in the right direction: [Create .ics file dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5750249/create-ics-file-dynamically)